# Stdout when running django as fastcgi

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi

I have configured my Django app to run under Apache+FastCGI on Linux (Ubuntu, if it matters). My question is: how to redirect stdout to a file when running Django as fastcgi.

**EDIT**
To clarify: I am familiar with django-logging module and yes I am using it already. This is not what my question is about.

Say when I run Django from the console as

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get all the requests, errors, etc shown in the console, which is stdout. However, when I run it as fastcgi under apache, where does stdout go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print statements should show up in your apache log. From the [docs](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html):

*"Data written to stdout or stderr before entering the FastCGI accept loop or via a mechanism that is not FastCGI protocol aware will also be directed to the main server log."*

You may need to set Apache's [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/core.html#loglevel) to **info** to view the same detail of information you get with runserver.